# How to add AppDelegate mainwindow xib in Singleview application

Tags: ios, mainwindow

I have `SingleView` application. Now I want to add a `mainwindow` to my project.

How can I add the `window` into my project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After editing sense of you problem changes. ....:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Add Your `LoginViewController` as `self.window.rootViewController`  such like

Add this code in your `Appdelegate.h` file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> 

{
    UIWindow *window;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

Add this code in your `Appdelegate.m` file
*(Here i also added UINavigationController too)*

```
  @synthesize window=_window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];

    LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *loginNVController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginViewController];
    loginNVController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    self.window.rootViewController = loginNVController;

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

**OR Add Directly**

Check this link for adding `window.xib` .
[Check this link](http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.in/2012/08/creating-our-own-mainwindowxib-for.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have choosen single view application. You can give the xib name as per the view. That is more general in sense. If you have selected empty application then go to you xcode project and add new file. which extends from UIViewController.

AppDelegate can not be referenced in any .xib files. the main method will instantiate AppDelegate object and AppDelegate object will then instance other view controllers.

For more you can read some apple documentation.

Thanks
Rinku

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpB-3TwJvQE&list=LLe3XfMWEoL1QSykSSxRCLTg&index=3